# How to load svg file and display in Fable.React?

Tags: f#, fable-f#

Things I have tried

```
img [Src "/myfile.svg"]
svg [Src "/myfile.svg"] []
svg [SVGAttr./*various options */ "/myfile.svg"] []
```

I also tried opening the svg in a text editor and copying the attributes

```
svg [
    SVGAttr.XlinkHref svgXlinkHref
    SVGAttr.Width "229"
    SVGAttr.Height "46"
    SVGAttr.ViewBox "0 0 229 46"
] []
```

Comment: Your code looks ok. Are you 100% sure about the path? What html is generated at the end?

Comment: @Guran Turns out the svg is just a base64 png image embedded in the svg. Not sure if that makes a difference but I got it to work by `img [Src "data:img/png;base64,iVBO...`.